# Why do my image links not work in chrome, even though they work in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have recently built and Ftp'd this site: (my personal portfolio site):

http://robert.young1.org

Under the section 'latest work', the first two links (Fine Art Site & Young Academy) work fine in Chrome. The next two links however, do not work at all in Chrome, even though they work in IE.

Does anyone have an inkling as to why?

My code for that section is as follows:

```
<div class="latest_work">

    <h2>Latest Work</h2>

    <hr />


    <div class="grid_7">

        <h3>Fine Art site</h3>                  

        <a href="http://robert.young1.org/fineart.php"><img src="img/fine_art resized.png" width="317" height="200" class="grid_5"></a>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_7 omega" id="right">

        <h3>Young Academy site</h3>

        <a href="http://robert.young1.org/youngacademy.php"><img src="img/young_academy.png" width="317" height="200" class="grid_5"></a>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_7">

        <h3 class="grid_7">Pinner Walks site</h3>

        <a href="http://robert.young1.org/pinnerwalks.php"><img src="img/pinner_walks resized.png" width="317" height="200" class="grid_5"></a>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_7 omega" id="right">

        <h3>PSLK </h3>

        <a href="http://robert.young1.org/pslk.php"><img src="img/pslk resized.png" width="317" height="200" class="grid_5"></a>



    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .latest_work {
    margin-top: 220px;
}






.latest_work h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.latest_work img {
    color: #999;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #f0eeed;
    opacity: .9;
}

.latest_work img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    color: #666;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

Thanks,

Regards,

Robert

London, UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because without any styling, the 'Other projects' overlaps the links as seen here:

[image: Overlapping]

Obviously with styling, it's still overlapping, just moved down a little. To fix this, you could do this:

`.grid_7{position:relative;z-index:999;}`

Comment: Thanks BeatAlex, you're a star! But how did you get the screenshot as above? By disabling all CSS styles?

Comment: @Rob644 Yes, I disabled all the CSS styles to see where it originally sat without any styling. I used Chrome :) The site looks good btw!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using id="right" many times which is incorrect.

Also try to use selectors in right way :

```
.latest_work a:hover img{
   opacity: 1.0;
   color: #666;
   border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close  tag many time, that is cause for error.